# JPA Specification and Criteria Builder JOIN Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have two related entities and I want to perfom pagination and filtering using JPA Specification and Criteria Builer API.
The first entity is User entitty:

```
@Table(name="users")
```

public class User implements UserDetails {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String otherName;
private String phoneNumber;
private String nextOfKeen;
private String nextOfKeenEmail;
private String nextOfKeenPhone;
private String nationality;
private String profession;
private Boolean loggedIn;
@Column(columnDefinition="float default 0.0")
private double wallet;
@Column(columnDefinition="float default 0.0")
private double totalDeposit;
@Column(columnDefinition="float default 0.0")
private double totalWithdrawals;
private String nextOfKeenRelation;
@Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
private String email;
@Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
private String username;
@JsonIgnore
private String password;
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="branch_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private Branch branch;

private String idNumber;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="membership_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private Membership membership;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
}
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}
The Second entity is the Payment entity:

```
@Entity
```

public class Payment {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.UUID)
private UUID id;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private User user;
private double amount;
private LocalDateTime transactionDate;

@Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
private String transactionCode;
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
```

}
From the research I have gathered online, I have been able to implement specification and criteria api as below:

```
public class PaymentSpecification {
public static Specification<Payment> getUserPayments(Long userId,String search){
    return(root,query,criteriaBuilder)->{
        Join<Payment, User> userJoin = root.join("user");
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if(search.isEmpty()) {
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(userJoin.get("id"),userId);
        }else {
            Predicate amount = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("amount"), "%"+search+"%");
            predicates.add(amount);
            
            Predicate firstName = criteriaBuilder.like(userJoin.get("firstName"), "%"+search+"%");
            predicates.add(firstName);
            
            Predicate lastName = criteriaBuilder.like(userJoin.get("lastName"), "%"+search+"%");
            predicates.add(lastName);
            
            Predicate otherName = criteriaBuilder.like(userJoin.get("otherName"), "%"+search+"%");
            
            predicates.add(otherName);
            
            Predicate userPayment = criteriaBuilder.equal(userJoin.get("id"),userId);
            
            return criteriaBuilder.and(userPayment,criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
            
        }
    };
}
```

}
And implemented the specification in the service as follows:

```
@Override
        public Page<Payment> getUserPayments(long userId, int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField,
                String sortOrder, String searchValue, String filterField, String filterValue) {
            try {
                PaymentSpecification paymentSpecification = new PaymentSpecification();
                Page<Payment> payments;
                final Pageable paging;
                if (sortOrder.equals("DESC")) {
                    paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize).withSort(Sort.Direction.DESC, sortField);
                } else {
                    paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize).withSort(Sort.Direction.ASC, sortField);
                }
                return paymentRepository.findAll(paymentSpecification.getUserPayments(userId, searchValue),paging);
```

}
When I try to call the endpoint **localhost:8081/api/v1/users/3/payments** through this controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{userId}/payments")
public ResponseEntity<Page<Payment>> getUserPayments(@PathVariable("userId") long userId,@RequestParam Optional<Integer> page,@RequestParam Optional <Integer> pageSize,@RequestParam Optional<String> sortField,@RequestParam Optional<String> order, @RequestParam Optional<String> searchValue,@RequestParam Optional<String>filterField,@RequestParam Optional<String>filterValue){
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(paymentService.getUserPayments(userId,page.orElse(0), pageSize.orElse(50),sortField.orElse("name"),order.orElse("ASC"),searchValue.orElse(""),filterField.orElse(""),filterValue.orElse("")));
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> 2023-02-24T06:02:48.373+03:00  WARN 12841 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [*.exception.RequestException: No property 'name' found for type 'Payment']

From all the research I have done, I have not been able to solve the issue, since I am still new to Spring boot. Any assistance in the solving the error shall be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

##### Error Slove

first of all ,slove your confusion that  the occur error

- `No property 'name' found for type 'Payment']`

The request  you  provide `localhost:8081/api/v1/users/3/payments`  that seems like with no parameter , so that the code snippet `sortField.orElse("name")` will value  `name`  . you can slove it by add parameter with your request , such as

```
localhost:8081/api/v1/users/3/payments/1?page=1&pageSize=2&sortField=lastName
```

##### Suggestion

- Build entity
- Modify your controller signature
- The request format

###### Build entity

it is more convenient that build a entity  to receive all query parameter

```
public class QueryParameter{
     private Integer page;
     private Integer pageSize;
     private String sortField;
     private String sortOrder;
     private String searchValue;
     private String filterField;
     private String filterValue;
}
```

###### Modify controller

make the controller more general , you should modify your method signature . Considering the subsequent demand expansion , it is better to choose json as the  request parameter formate ; In my opinion ,it is more ordinary to  modify entity than modify controller signature;

```
@GetMapping("/{userId}/payments")
public ResponseEntity<Page<Payment>> getUserPayments(@PathVariable("userId") long userId,@RequestBody QueryParameter queryParameter){
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(paymentService.getUserPayments(userId,queryParameter.getPage(), queryParameter.getpageSize(),queryParameter.getName(),queryParameter.getName().getortField(),queryParameter.getSearchValue(),queryParameter.getFilterField（）,queryParameter.getFilterValue()));
}
```

###### The request format

do the  request as below

```
localhost:8081/api/v1/users/3/payments/1
```

and the parameter is below

```
{

"page":1,
"pageSize":50,
"sortField":"amount",
}
```

hopes the contents may helpful for you